# How to get array from a closure object in php

Tags: php

I have an object which yields the following when var_dump()ed

```
object(Closure)#78 (3) {
  ["static"]=>
     array(3) {
        ...
     }
}
```

Is there a means by which i can retrieve the array labeled static?

I have tried the following:

```
ReflectionClass::getProperty('static');//returns property static does not exit

ReflectionClass::getStaticPropertyValue('static');//Class Closure does not have a property named static

ReflectionClass::getProperties();// returns an empty array

ReflectionClass::getStaticProperties();//returns an empty array

$obj->static;//Closure object cannot have properties

get_obj_vars($obj);//returns an empty array

(array)$obj;//wraps $obj in an array, but does not CONVERT to an array

json_decode(json_encode($obj));//returns object(stdClass)#79 (0) {}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Just access the array as it is a normal property: `print_r($yourVar->static);`

Comment: @Rizier123: I have also tried that it gives this error: Closure object cannot have properties

Comment: Why are you poking around the internals of a closure in the first place?

Comment: @deceze: A set of rules are defined within it. I want to do some process based on those rules without having to duplicate the rules in an array or something. Which will mean 2 set of rules to maintain. Now why dont i just use arrays alone? Well the closure is generated automatically by the framework i use. I dont have control over that. Hence i'm poking the closure for the ruleset.

Comment: The implementation details of closures are incidental and not an official stable API you should depend on. Logically you don't have access to closed-over variables from outside the closure. You should not depend on implementation specific hacks, if one exists at all, to achieve something you logically shouldn't be able to.

Comment: Thanks all for your opinions. I have figured out another way to access the rule set. So no need to poke into the closure any more. Thanks again! Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The `static` property you see here is an implementation detail of the `\Closure` class and solely internal to PHP. The class captures the `use`d variables in this property.

You cannot access this property and the only thing you can do with a `\Closure` object is calling it or passing it around.

Via reflection you can only access the scope using [`ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getClosureScopeClass`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getclosurescopeclass.php) and [`ReflectionFunctionAbstract::getClosureThis`](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionfunctionabstract.getclosurethis.php) respectively.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static function getRegistrar($callable)
    {
        if(is_callable($callable))
        {
            if(is_a($callable,'Closure'))
            {
                preg_match_all('/\[this\] => (.+) Object/', print_r($callable,true), $matches);
                if(count($matches)>1)
                    return $matches[1];
            }
            else if (is_array($callable) && count($callable)>0 && is_a($callable[0],'Object'))
            {
                return gettype($callable[0]);
            }


        }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I see you have built a wall of code. Can you explain what this does, please?